# Powershell script for relaying data between sftp server and Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sftp

Good morning all,

I have a project at work where I need to upload/download between a Sharepoint server and SFTP server.
The steps are like so:

1. Periodically check sftp server for data (2 different servers)
2. download to Windows server any new data
3. upload data from Windows server to Sharepoint
4. Periodically check Sharepoint server for data
5. download to Windows server any new data
6. upload data from Windows server to sftp server

I have scripts to connect to Sharepoint, and to connect to sftp server, and they will be below. The problem I am having is listing folders/files, and downloading/uploading them. When I try to list certain folders in Sharepoint, it give me everything. I am unable to list folders in SFTP.

I would like to download/upload folders and add a timestamp onto them. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

**SFTP connect script:**

```
$Uname = "my username"
$Pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\cred.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Uname, $Pass

New-SFTPSession 127.0.0.1 -Credential $Cred

Get-ChildItem
```

**Sharepoint connect script:**

```
$Uname = "email address"
$Pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\cred.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Uname, $Pass


#Connect to SPO
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenantname.sharepoint.com -Credentials $Cred
$web = Get-SPWeb https://tenantname.sharepoint.com
$list = $web.Lists["Style Library"]
$fields = $list.Fields.InternalName
$fields | Where-Object {
    $_ -like '*sitename*'
}
```

**Sharepoint download single file script**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null

$Uname = "email address"
$Pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\cred.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Uname, $Pass
$SiteURL = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name"
$LibraryName = "Documents"
$FolderName = "2020"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

#Config Variables
$FileRelativeURL = "/sites/site_name/Shared Documents/2020/file_name"
$DownloadPath ="C:\Temp"


Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

    #powershell download file from sharepoint online
    Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -Path $DownloadPath -AsFile
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way in which I did this, was to actually map the locations as Driver letters in Windows Explorer on the Server

Script would go as follows:

- Delete old listing of the drive
- Map drive using URL of SP Site/Document Library (Your comments in the code suggest you are using SPO)
- Run the rest of your requiremnts